# How to create a line chart with two line, with one of them being filled, and the other staying on the foreground of the filled line?

Tags: chart.js, chart.js3

I have the following chart:

[image]

**How can I make sure that the the blue line isn't filled, but at the same time, stays on top of the filled red line?**

Taking the line chart example from the documentation, I have tried playing around with the `drawTime` property, but as you can see, the blue line is on the foreground of the red one, *but it is filled* (I expect the blue line to be on the foreground, but not filled).

Here's what I have so far:

Data:

```js
const data = {
  labels: generateLabels(),
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      data: generateData(),
      borderColor: Utils.CHART_COLORS.red,
      backgroundColor: Utils.CHART_COLORS.red,
      fill: true
    },
    {
      label: 'Dataset 2',
      data: generateData(),
      borderColor: Utils.CHART_COLORS.blue,
      backgroundColor: Utils.transparentize(Utils.CHART_COLORS.blue),
      // changed `fill` propery from `true` to `false`
      fill: false
    }
  ]
};
```

Config:

```js
const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: {
    plugins: {
      filler: {
        propagate: false,
        // added `drawTime` property here
        drawTime: "beforeDraw",
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: (ctx) => 'drawTime: ' + ctx.chart.options.plugins.filler.drawTime
      }
    },
    pointBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    radius: 10,
    interaction: {
      intersect: false,
    }
  },
};
```

Setup:

```
const inputs = {
  min: -100,
  max: 100,
  count: 8,
  decimals: 2,
  continuity: 1
};

const generateLabels = () => {
  return Utils.months({count: inputs.count});
};

Utils.srand(3);
const generateData = () => (Utils.numbers(inputs));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a bug in chart.js itself.
You have 3 options:

- wait until it is fixed within chart.js itself
- write your own custom plugin that does the filling
- make use of the order property so the blue line gets drawn on the canvas after the red one like so:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        borderColor: 'red',
        fill: true,
        order: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'blue',
        order: 0
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {}
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.0/chart.js"></script>

<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```

**EDIT:**
After looking at the source code it seems indeed like its a bug in chart.js, it does not check if fill has been set to false so it will always fill with the non default modes. Will put in a fix for this so it will be fixed in version 3.8.1

Comment: Thank you very much! I've used the `order` property and it works. 
Once the bugfix is merged, I'll use the `drawTime` property.